# rewrite rule not working: redirect to php script if file exists

Tags: rewrite-rules

I wanted to use `add_rewrite_rule` but had no success.

What I want to achieve is that if the URL `www.myhomepage.com/custom-media-files/2/screenshot_15_1.jpg` is opened, that the user is redirected to a php script located in `www.myhomepage.com/screenshotaccess.php` where I check if the user has the permission to open the file.

Edit:
So i tried to edit htaccess file it now looks likes this, but it still not working. It seems that the rule does not apply when a file is stored directly behind the URL. If i go to a URL where no file is located, the rule works.

```
#BEGIN screenshotaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/$ https://google.com [L]
RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/([0-9]+)/$ https://google.com [L]
#RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/(.+)/screenshot_trade_(.+)_(.+)\.jpg$ https://google.com [L]
RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/(.+)/screenshot_trade_(.+)_(.+)\.jpg$ /screenshotaccess.php?usrid=$1&fn=$2&i=$3 [L]

#END screenshotaccess
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the rewrite rules wont work is because you'll find that if you look at your .htaccess file, WordPress doesn't actually load if the file that is being requested is present on-disk.

So if they try to access an image file, because it's there, on disk, WordPress isn't loaded and so the rewrite rules have no affect.

You may want to use .htaccess rules. Here is an example of what you could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/(.+)/screenshot_trade_(.+)_(.+)\.jpg$ /screenshotaccess.php?usrid=$1&fn=$2&i=$3 [L]
```

I'd also make sure in your `screenshotaccess.php` that you're not just using your query/`$_GET` vars without first checking they're of the correct format - i.e. you're santizing your data before you use it.

Comment: thanks for the tipp. I first tried to solve my issue with editing the htaccess, but i had no success at all, thats why i tried it with the wp function. I tried your lines, but still no success. Is it right to add the two lines right after the # END WordPress text?

Comment: So i tried everything. Inside or outside of the # WordPress. Also just RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/$ but also no success. The lines seem to be ignored.

Comment: these lines should come before the WordPress lines... and is your `screenshotaccess.php` definitely there in the right place? (the root of your website)

Comment: So even a simple rule like "RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/([0-9])/$ /default-redirect-page/ [L]" does not work.

Comment: start building it up til you get something to work and so you know you're on the right track, e.g.
`RewriteRule .* https://google.com  [L]`
then
`RewriteRule / https://google.com [L]`
then
`RewriteRule ^/custom.* https://google.com [L]`

The point being... start experimenting, be creative and start with the most simple rules you can think of and build up until it breaks. You haven't "tried everything", until you tried everything

Comment: Thanks a lot. So those simple rules are working now. The rewrite rule does not work, if the url exactly points to a file. Why is that? e.g. the url is https://whatever.com/custom-media-files/2/screenshot_trade_79_1.jpg, at that url a jpeg file is located and the rewrite rule RewriteRule ^custom-media-files/(.+)/screenshot_trade_(.+)_(.+)\.jpg$ https://google.com [L] is not working. If i go to a URL where no file is located e.g https://whatever.com/custom-media-files/2/screenshot_trade_99_1.jpg, the rewrite rule works!?

Comment: actually, now that I think on it, perhaps what you want to try is redirect instead:
`Redirect ^custom-media-files/(.+)/screenshot_trade_(.+)_(.+)\.jpg$ /screenshotaccess.php?usrid=$1&fn=$2&i=$3`. Try that, and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi! No success, still the same behaviour, files are just loaded instantly without redirection. Probably i need to use soimething with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ??

Comment: when removing the \.jpg in the rule, and opening url /custom-media-files/screenshot_trade_6_12 without the jpg ending, the rule works correctly! So why does it not work when a file is located under the url?